# Artemis crashed and messages/queues lost

Tags: activemq-artemis

Any ideas what happened here? Can messages and queues be restored? How to use ActiveMQ Artemis data? All queues/messages are lost. Only DLQ/ExpiryQueue.

1. We had to do a configuration change. So we started updating the Slave.
2. To failover to the Slave to fix the Master we did a `./artemis-service stop` @16:32
3. Some warnings on Master but not much else.
4. On the Slave we can see some timeouts and connection failures. Not sure if Slave took over the Queues and worked ok or not.
5. @16:46:27 we did a `./artemis-service start` on the Master
6. Seems like Artemis started moving/removing bindings/journals
7. Master seems to fail to start with Connections issues @16:46:33
8. Slave tries to restart again and take control @16:46:37
9. Slave cleans out journals/bindings

And now all queues are gone. Only DLQ and ExpiryQueue exists on Slave. Master is down.

Can we restore from `oldreplica`? Might be wiped already?
We have not yet ried to restore from Replicas. Is there a manual or KnowledgeBase?

Master:
A few of these:

```
16:32:15,847 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222061: Client connection failed, clearing up resources for session ID:xxx.yyy.zzz-30305-1552451287008-17:1:-1 
16:32:15,847 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222107: Cleared up resources for session ID:xxx.yyy.zzz-30305-1552451287008-17:1:-1 
...
16:32:16,088 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.plugin.PluginContextListener] Destroyed artemis-plugin plugin 
16:32:16,093 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.branding.PluginContextListener] Destroyed activemq-branding plugin 
16:32:16,104 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221002: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.4.0 [06926557-2906-11e8-a15f-005056926b6e] stopped, uptime 4 days 3 hours
```

Meanwhile on the Slave:

```
16:32:15,867 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221066: Initiating quorum vote: LiveFailoverQuorumVote 
16:32:15,868 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221067: Waiting 30 seconds for quorum vote results. 
16:32:15,869 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221068: Received all quorum votes. 
16:32:15,869 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221071: Failing over based on quorum vote results. 
16:32:15,889 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119015: The connection was disconnected because of server shutdown [code=DISCONNECTED] 
16:32:15,944 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119015: The connection was disconnected because of server shutdown [code=DISCONNECTED] 
16:32:15,999 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221037: ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=06926557-2906-11e8-a15f-005056926b6e to become 'live' 
16:32:16,450 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212004: Failed to connect to server. 
16:32:34,825 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying queue DLQ on address DLQ 
16:32:34,825 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying queue ExpiryQueue on address ExpiryQueue 
16:32:35,156 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221007: Server is now live 

16:33:51,161 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119014: Did not receive data from /aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:53781 within the 60,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT] 
16:34:10,061 INFO  [io.hawt.web.LoginServlet] hawtio login is using 1800 sec. HttpSession timeout 
16:34:11,891 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) while handshaking has occurred. 
16:34:52,912 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) while handshaking has occurred. 
16:35:01,183 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119014: Did not receive data from /aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:47171 within the 60,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT] 
16:36:01,191 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119014: Did not receive data from /aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:54700 within the 60,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT] 
16:36:12,705 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) while handshaking has occurred. 
16:36:53,104 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) while handshaking has occurred. 
16:37:11,203 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119014: Did not receive data from /aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:16751 within the 60,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT] 
16:38:11,209 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119014: Did not receive data from /aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:20634 within the 60,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT] 
16:38:12,182 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) while handshaking has occurred. 
16:39:21,216 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119014: Did not receive data from /aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:61541 within the 60,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT] 
16:40:21,225 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119014: Did not receive data from /aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:49708 within the 60,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT] 
16:41:18,720 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) while handshaking has occurred. 
16:45:51,271 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119014: Did not receive data from /aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:20748 within the 60,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT] 
16:46:32,151 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221025: Replication: sending AIOSequentialFile:/opt/brokers/ActiveMQServer2/./data/journal/activemq-data-167.amq (size=10,485,760) to replica. 
16:46:33,100 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221025: Replication: sending AIOSequentialFile:/opt/brokers/ActiveMQServer2/./data/journal/activemq-data-168.amq (size=10,485,760) to replica. 
16:46:33,182 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222061: Client connection failed, clearing up resources for session ID:xxx.yyy.zzz-30305-1552451287008-19:1:-1 
16:46:33,188 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222107: Cleared up resources for session ID:xxx.yyy.zzz-30305-1552451287008-19:1:-1 
16:46:33,199 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222061: Client connection failed, clearing up resources for session 380d4fc6-4f13-11e9-b0fb-00505692a0af 
16:46:33,288 INFO  [io.hawt.web.AuthenticationFilter] Destroying hawtio authentication filter 
16:46:33,290 INFO  [io.hawt.HawtioContextListener] Destroying hawtio services 
16:46:33,391 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.plugin.PluginContextListener] Destroyed artemis-plugin plugin 
16:46:33,397 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.branding.PluginContextListener] Destroyed activemq-branding plugin 
16:46:33,408 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221002: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.4.0 [06926557-2906-11e8-a15f-005056926b6e] stopped, uptime 4 days 3 hours 


16:46:37,163 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.bootstrap] AMQ101000: Starting ActiveMQ Artemis Server 
16:46:37,266 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221000: backup Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=true,journalDirectory=./data/journal,bindingsDirectory=./data/bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=./data/large-messages,pagingDirectory=./data/paging) 
16:46:37,288 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221055: There were too many old replicated folders upon startup, removing /opt/brokers/ActiveMQServer2/./data/bindings/oldreplica.45 
16:46:37,292 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222162: Moving data directory /opt/brokers/ActiveMQServer2/./data/bindings to /opt/brokers/ActiveMQServer2/./data/bindings/oldreplica.47 
16:46:37,295 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221055: There were too many old replicated folders upon startup, removing /opt/brokers/ActiveMQServer2/./data/journal/oldreplica.49 
16:46:37,597 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222162: Moving data directory /opt/brokers/ActiveMQServer2/./data/journal to /opt/brokers/ActiveMQServer2/./data/journal/oldreplica.51 
16:46:37,628 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221055: There were too many old replicated folders upon startup, removing /opt/brokers/ActiveMQServer2/./data/paging/oldreplica.45 
16:46:37,852 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.branding.PluginContextListener] Initialized activemq-branding plugin 
16:46:38,056 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222162: Moving data directory /opt/brokers/ActiveMQServer2/./data/paging to /opt/brokers/ActiveMQServer2/./data/paging/oldreplica.47 
16:46:38,091 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221012: Using AIO Journal 
16:46:38,157 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221057: Global Max Size is being adjusted to 1/2 of the JVM max size (-Xmx). being defined as 2,147,483,648 
16:46:38,252 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-server]. Adding protocol support for: CORE 
16:46:38,252 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-amqp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: AMQP 
16:46:38,253 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-hornetq-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: HORNETQ 
16:46:38,253 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-mqtt-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: MQTT 
16:46:38,253 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-openwire-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: OPENWIRE 
16:46:38,254 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-stomp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: STOMP 
16:46:38,328 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.plugin.PluginContextListener] Initialized artemis-plugin plugin 
16:46:42,502 INFO  [io.hawt.HawtioContextListener] Initialising hawtio services 
16:46:42,572 INFO  [io.hawt.web.JolokiaConfiguredAgentServlet] Jolokia overridden property: [key=policyLocation, value=file:/opt/brokers/ActiveMQServer2//etc/jolokia-access.xml] 
16:46:42,617 INFO  [io.hawt.web.RBACMBeanInvoker] Using MBean [hawtio:type=security,area=jmx,rank=0,name=HawtioDummyJMXSecurity] for role based access control 
16:46:42,788 INFO  [io.hawt.system.ProxyWhitelist] Initial proxy whitelist: [localhost, 127.0.0.1, aaa.bbb.ccc.50, nodep02.domain.local] 
16:46:43,202 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241001: HTTP Server started at http://nodep02:8161
16:46:43,202 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241002: Artemis Jolokia REST API available at http://nodep02:8161/console/jolokia
```

Back on the Master

```
16:46:27,913 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.bootstrap] AMQ101000: Starting ActiveMQ Artemis Server 
16:46:27,999 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221000: live Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=true,journalDirectory=./data/journal,bindingsDirectory=./data/bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=./data/large-messages,pagingDirectory=./data/paging) 
16:46:28,440 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221055: There were too many old replicated folders upon startup, removing /opt/brokers/ActiveMQServer1/./data/bindings/oldreplica.18 
16:46:28,447 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222162: Moving data directory /opt/brokers/ActiveMQServer1/./data/bindings to /opt/brokers/ActiveMQServer1/./data/bindings/oldreplica.20 
16:46:28,450 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221055: There were too many old replicated folders upon startup, removing /opt/brokers/ActiveMQServer1/./data/journal/oldreplica.18 
16:46:28,478 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222162: Moving data directory /opt/brokers/ActiveMQServer1/./data/journal to /opt/brokers/ActiveMQServer1/./data/journal/oldreplica.20 
16:46:28,482 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221055: There were too many old replicated folders upon startup, removing /opt/brokers/ActiveMQServer1/./data/paging/oldreplica.18 
16:46:28,517 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222162: Moving data directory /opt/brokers/ActiveMQServer1/./data/paging to /opt/brokers/ActiveMQServer1/./data/paging/oldreplica.20 
16:46:28,580 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221012: Using AIO Journal 
16:46:33,209 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119015: The connection was disconnected because of server shutdown [code=DISCONNECTED] 
16:46:33,266 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119015: The connection was disconnected because of server shutdown [code=DISCONNECTED] 
16:46:33,273 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal] File not opened, file=null: java.lang.NullPointerException: File not opened, file=null 
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.aio.AIOSequentialFile.checkOpened(AIOSequentialFile.java:328) [artemis-journal-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0] 
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.aio.AIOSequentialFile.writeDirect(AIOSequentialFile.java:242) [artemis-journal-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0] 
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.AbstractSequentialFile$LocalBufferObserver.flushBuffer(AbstractSequentialFile.java:306) [artemis-journal-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0] 
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.buffer.TimedBuffer.flushBatch(TimedBuffer.java:310) [artemis-journal-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0] 
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.buffer.TimedBuffer.flush(TimedBuffer.java:281) [artemis-journal-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0] 
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.AbstractSequentialFileFactory.flush(AbstractSequentialFileFactory.java:195) [artemis-journal-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0] 
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl.flush(JournalImpl.java:2194) [artemis-journal-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0] 
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl.stop(JournalImpl.java:2356) [artemis-journal-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0] 
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.journal.JournalStorageManager.stop(JournalStorageManager.java:266) [artemis-server-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0] 
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.journal.JournalStorageManager.stop(JournalStorageManager.java:203) [artemis-server-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0] 
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.replication.ReplicationEndpoint.stop(ReplicationEndpoint.java:327) [artemis-server-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0] 
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.stopComponent(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:1256) [artemis-server-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0] 
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.SharedNothingBackupActivation.run(SharedNothingBackupActivation.java:259) [artemis-server-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0] 
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$ActivationThread.run(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:2951) [artemis-server-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0] 
16:46:33,318 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224000: Failure in initialisation: ActiveMQIllegalStateException[errorType=ILLEGAL_STATE message=AMQ119026: Backup Server was not yet in sync with live] 
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.SharedNothingBackupActivation.run(SharedNothingBackupActivation.java:314) [artemis-server-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0] 
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$ActivationThread.run(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:2951) [artemis-server-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0] 
16:46:33,995 INFO  [io.hawt.web.keycloak.KeycloakServlet] Keycloak integration is disabled 
16:46:40,486 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222040: Server is stopped 
16:46:50,033 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222040: Server is stopped 
16:47:00,034 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222040: Server is stopped
```

Broker.xml (Master)

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration xmlns="urn:activemq" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">
        <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">
            <name>ActiveMQ1</name>
            <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
            <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>
            <paging-directory>./data/paging</paging-directory>
            <bindings-directory>./data/bindings</bindings-directory>
            <journal-directory>./data/journal</journal-directory>
            <large-messages-directory>./data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>
            <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>
            <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>
            <journal-pool-files>-1</journal-pool-files>
            <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
            <journal-buffer-size>33554432</journal-buffer-size>
            <!-- Size in bytes -->
            <journal-buffer-timeout>128000</journal-buffer-timeout>
            <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>
            <connectors>
                <connector name="artemis">tcp://nodep01:61616</connector>
                <connector name="ActiveMQ2-Connector">tcp://nodep02:61616</connector>
            </connectors>
            <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>
            <max-disk-usage>100</max-disk-usage>
            <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>
            <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>
            <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>
            <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>
            <acceptors>
                <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://nodep01:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300</acceptor>
                <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://nodep01:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpMinCredits=300</acceptor>
                <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://nodep01:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
                <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://nodep01:5445?protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
                <acceptor name="artemis+ssl">tcp://nodep01:61443?sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=/opt/brokers/ActiveMQServer1/activemq.keystore;keyStorePassword=CCCCC;tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300</acceptor>
            </acceptors>
            <cluster-user>XXXXXXXX</cluster-user>
            <cluster-password>YYYYYYY</cluster-password>
            <cluster-connections>
                <cluster-connection name="ActiveMQClusterPROD">
                    <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
                    <min-large-message-size>33554432</min-large-message-size>
                    <!-- Size should be eqvialent to journal-buffer-size -->
                    <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
                    <max-hops>1</max-hops>
                    <static-connectors>
                        <connector-ref>ActiveMQ2-Connector</connector-ref>
                    </static-connectors>
                </cluster-connection>
            </cluster-connections>
            <ha-policy>
                <replication>
                    <master>
                        <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
                    </master>
                </replication>
            </ha-policy>
            <security-settings>
                <security-setting match="#">
                    <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
                    <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
                    <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
                    <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
                    <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq" />
                    <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq" />
                    <permission type="consume" roles="amq" />
                    <permission type="browse" roles="amq" />
                    <permission type="send" roles="amq" />
                    <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work-->
                    <permission type="manage" roles="amq" />
                </security-setting>
            </security-settings>
            <address-settings>
                <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
                <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
                    <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                    <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                    <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                    <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
                    <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
                    <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                    <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                    <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
                    <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
                    <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
                    <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
                </address-setting>
                <!--default for catch all-->
                <address-setting match="#">
                    <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                    <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                    <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                    <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
                    <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
                    <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                    <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                    <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
                    <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
                    <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
                    <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
                </address-setting>
            </address-settings>
            <addresses>
                <address name="DLQ">
                    <anycast>
                        <queue name="DLQ" />
                    </anycast>
                </address>
                <address name="ExpiryQueue">
                    <anycast>
                        <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
                    </anycast>
                </address>
            </addresses>
        </core>
    </configuration>
```

Broker.xml (Slave)

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration xmlns="urn:activemq" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">
        <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">
            <name>ActiveMQ2</name>
            <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
            <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>
            <paging-directory>./data/paging</paging-directory>
            <bindings-directory>./data/bindings</bindings-directory>
            <journal-directory>./data/journal</journal-directory>
            <large-messages-directory>./data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>
            <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>
            <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>
            <journal-pool-files>-1</journal-pool-files>
            <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
            <journal-buffer-size>33554432</journal-buffer-size>
            <!-- size in bytes -->
            <journal-buffer-timeout>104000</journal-buffer-timeout>
            <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>
            <connectors>
                <!-- Connector used to be announced through cluster connections and notifications -->
                <connector name="artemis">tcp://nodep02:61616</connector>
                <connector name="ActiveMQ1-Connector">tcp://nodep01:61616</connector>
            </connectors>
            <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>
            <max-disk-usage>100</max-disk-usage>
            <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>
            <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>
            <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>
            <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>
            <acceptors>
                <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://nodep02:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300</acceptor>
                <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://nodep02:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpMinCredits=300</acceptor>
                <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://nodep02:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
                <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://nodep02:5445?protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
                <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://nodep02:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
                <acceptor name="artemis+ssl">tcp://nodep02:61443?sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=/opt/brokers/ActiveMQServer2/activemq.keystore;keyStorePassword=CCCCC;tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300</acceptor>
            </acceptors>
            <cluster-user>XXXXXXXX</cluster-user>
            <cluster-password>YYYYYYY</cluster-password>
            <cluster-connections>
                <cluster-connection name="ActiveMQClusterPROD">
                    <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
                    <min-large-message-size>33554432</min-large-message-size>
                    <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
                    <max-hops>1</max-hops>
                    <static-connectors>
                        <connector-ref>ActiveMQ1-Connector</connector-ref>
                    </static-connectors>
                </cluster-connection>
            </cluster-connections>
            <ha-policy>
                <replication>
                    <slave>
                        <allow-failback>true</allow-failback>
                    </slave>
                </replication>
            </ha-policy>
            <security-settings>
                <security-setting match="#">
                    <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
                    <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
                    <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
                    <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
                    <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq" />
                    <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq" />
                    <permission type="consume" roles="amq" />
                    <permission type="browse" roles="amq" />
                    <permission type="send" roles="amq" />
                    <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work-->
                    <permission type="manage" roles="amq" />
                </security-setting>
            </security-settings>
            <address-settings>
                <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
                <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
                    <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                    <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                    <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                    <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
                    <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
                    <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                    <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                    <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
                    <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
                    <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
                    <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
                </address-setting>
                <!--default for catch all-->
                <address-setting match="#">
                    <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                    <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                    <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                    <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
                    <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
                    <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                    <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                    <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
                    <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
                    <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
                    <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
                </address-setting>
            </address-settings>
            <addresses>
                <address name="DLQ">
                    <anycast>
                        <queue name="DLQ" />
                    </anycast>
                </address>
                <address name="ExpiryQueue">
                    <anycast>
                        <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
                    </anycast>
                </address>
            </addresses>
        </core>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: All Queues were "deleted/removed". When it failed over to secondary only DLQ and ExpiryQueue Queues were present. The rest of our queues were gone.

Comment: Edited above. More errors.

Comment: Updated Broker.xml above.

1. ./artemis-service stop
2. secondary tried to take over (but I suspect it failed.)
3. About 7-10 min after I stopped master I typed ./artemis-service start
4. Looks like Master never took back control from secondary.

Comment: Updated and cleaned. Had to remove som INFO to fit in one POST. Thank you. Is there a good manual or KB on how to restore after a fail from Replicas?

Comment: How are you confirming that all queues were deleted/removed? The only addresses & queues defined in your configuration are `DLQ` and `ExpiryQueue` so it looks like everything is working as expected. If you're using auto-created addresses & queues the broker will not log information about deploying those when it starts.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for you assistance. 
We use the hawtio GUI for mangement and to create queues. After the Failover there were no queues on either QueueMgr (Master/Slave) when we logged in. The Producers could not connect and produce messages. Our consumers could not connect and consume messages. Zero messages on DLQ. It had messages before the failed failover. Yes, we will only see DLQ and ExpiryQueue created in logs. We always create our Durable queues in Hawtio. We find it as a great disadvantage to specify queues in Broker.xml because a restart is needed to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore the full journal from the "oldreplica" backups. That's what they're there for. You simply need to copy the files from the backup location to the original location. As always, be careful when copying data so that you don't overwrite something you might need later.

Comment: When we did./artemis-service stop it failed over to secondary/slave. But only DLQ/ExpiryQueue came up after the failover.

Comment: Replicas seems to have been removed?

16:46:37,628 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221055: There were too many old replicated folders upon startup, removing /opt/brokers/ActiveMQServer2/./data/paging/oldreplica.45 

16:46:28,478 INFO  AMQ222162: Moving data directory /opt/brokers/ActiveMQServer1/./data/journal to /opt/brokers/Ac 
tiveMQServer1/./data/journal/oldreplica.20 
16:46:28,482 INFO  AMQ221055: There were too many old replicated folders upon startup, removing /opt/brokers/Activ 
eMQServer1/./data/paging/oldreplica.18

Comment: Did you attempt to restore any of the backups? I was addressing your question about whether or not you could restore from "oldreplica" backups.

Comment: Old replicas are removed based on the configuration of `max-saved-replicated-journals-size` (which is `2` by default). The oldest replicas are removed first.

Comment: What is a good setting for ´max-saved-replicated-journals-size´. Two was too small as were removed very quickly. Any other setting that seems odd?

Comment: A "good" setting is one that fulfills your requirements. Set it to however many backups you want to keep.